# Render arbitrary Polygons in DirectX11

Tags: graphics, directx, rendering, polygon, directx-11

is there a way to render arbitrary polygons with n > 3 corners in directx 11?

i remember this being possible in older OpenGL versions with GL_POLYGON but i haven found anything in the directX API for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not natively, there is no NGons primitive types, and the GL ones were mostly full of issues and quite near of a FAN.

You will have to triangulate yourself, it can be done with a geometry shader, receiving the control points and outputing the triangles

A compute shader with a DrawIndirect is possible and more versatile but need more setup to work.